# File doesn't show up after downloading from google drive

Tags: python, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a Google Colab Notebook and I am unable to figure out where my file goes after I download.

I am trying to download a file called train.csv which is the dataset I use to train the model.I picked the following code up from the official google colab [guide](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb)

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')
import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

#figured out how to get the file id of my file
requests = drive_service.files().list(q="name='train.csv'").execute()
fid=requests.get('files')[0]['id']

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=fid)
downloaded = io.FileIO('./ColabNotebooks/train.csv')
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
while done is False:
    _, done = downloader.next_chunk()
downloaded.seek(0)
```

But after this, when I check the folder of the drive by: 
**!ls**, I don't see the file stored. I tried reading the file using pandas, but it showed an error. 
Where is the error? Why am I unable to get the file from my google drive and send it to the colab server ?

Comment: It doesn't go anywhere, it's in the `downloaded` variable (or will be once you iterate calling `downloader.next_chunk()`). If you want to save it somewhere, use `io.FileIO` instead of `BytesIO`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I made the edits. But it is unable to find the folder. It says the location does not exist. Did I do it wrong?